# How to close a bootstrap modal and redirect after success-alert displayed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm new to javascript/programming and I'm having trouble trying to close a bootstrap modal after a form submission returns with a alert-success message.  What I'd like to happen is for the user to:

1. submit a form embedded in the modal.
2. If successfully submitted,the alert-success message will display.
3. If the alert-success displays, I'd like to have the modal window close
4. (optionally) I'd like to reset the form

I've tried using javascript hide function but no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($('#alert-success'))
  {
   $('#myModal').hide();
  } 

});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Here is a sample code of what I'm trying to create (note: I've including dummy code since I don't have permission to use my company code here). link to code below found here also: http://jsbin.com/pidizetila/edit?html,output

```
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->


     <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;      </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert alert-success">
      <strong>Success!</strong> Indicates a successful or positive action.
    </div>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: better load the `jquery` and `bootstrap.min.js` in the end of the `body` tag. Because best practice obeys this rule.

Comment: there is no `form` in your code

Comment: This is just a sample--is like to close the modal when this alert shows. Is it possible to close modal I just based on the alert?

Answer (score 5):

This answer is just an example to give COMPLETE idea how to achieve, what OP asked in question.

**1. Submit a form embedded in the modal.**

Modal With From

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Form</h4>
            </div>
            <form id="myform" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label popup-label">First Name</label>
                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="control-label popup-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input required type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" value="">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="error">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger"> <strong>Error!</strong> There Are Too Many Errors</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitForm">Submit</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="reset">Cancel / Clear</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="thanks"></div>
```

Ajax to submit form

```
 $("#submitForm").click(function () {
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "process.php",
         data: $('#myform').serialize(),
         success: function (msg) {
             $("#thanks").html(msg)
             $("#myModal").modal('hide');
         },
         error: function () {
             $("#error").show();
         }
     });
 });
```

Assuming that server-side language is PHP

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['firstname'])) {
        $firstname = strip_tags($_POST['firstname']);
        $lastname = strip_tags($_POST['lastname']);
        //Do what ever you like to do next
        echo "<div class=\"alert alert-success\"><strong>Success!</strong> This Is Success Thanks Message. If everything go exactly as Planned.</div>";
    }
?>
```

Till here, Form values has been posted.

**2. If successfully submitted, the alert-success message will display.**

```
 success: function (msg) {
     $("#thanks").html(msg)
 },
```

After successfull call from Ajax, the success message will display;

```
 <div id="thanks"></div>
```

It's up to you If you wana put `<div id="thanks"></div>` inside modal body but I won't recommend it because the next step you asked is to auto close the modal so success message will only show for couple of seconds and modal gets closed.

**3. If the alert-success displays, I'd like to have the modal window close**

After successful call from Ajax this will auto close the modal

```
 success: function (msg) {
     $("#thanks").html(msg)
     $("#myModal").modal('hide');
 },
```

**4. (optionally) I'd like to reset the form**

After Successful Ajax call, Once the modal has been closed, following code will reset the form inputs if modal open again.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    //$(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    $(':input','#myform').val("");
});
```

Optionally If user put values in form and close the modal without posting it, following code can also reset the form if user open the modal again, `cancel/clear` button has id `reset` which is bind with the following code.

```
    $("#reset").click(function () {
        $(':input','#myform').val("");
    });
```

The last thing, make sure the complete JS code will be DOM ready

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   //Put JS code here
});
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7p9v1uam/)

In your attempt;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('#alert-success')){
        $('#myModal').hide(); <<<<----This is wrong
    } 
});
```

When closing modal with jQuery (not with bootstrap) should be like

```
$('#myModal').hide('hide'); <<<<----Correct
```

Answer (score 1):

You Could sleep for Sometime and then Redirect as below.

This Should be executed after Luanching modal.

Create a javascript function as below

```
function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}
```

Then Sleep and Redirect (Sleeping is just for showing the Success Alert)

```
            sleep(3000).then(() => {window.location.href = 'index.jsp';});
```

regards,
Antony Vilson